# How to install `Hat`

Tags: debugging, haskell, cabal, cabal-install, hat

I am trying to get the `Hat` debugger. When I try:

`cabal install hat` OR `cabal install hat -v`

At the end I get:

```
configure: error: in `/tmp/terminfo-0.4.0.0-17745/terminfo-0.4.0.0':
configure: error: curses headers could not be found, so this package cannot be built
See `config.log' for more details
Failed to install terminfo-0.4.0.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
haskeline-0.7.1.3 depends on terminfo-0.4.0.0 which failed to install.
hat-2.8.0.0 depends on terminfo-0.4.0.0 which failed to install.
terminfo-0.4.0.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

So trouble shooting I try:

```
cabal install terminfo
```

And get:

```
configure: error: in `/tmp/terminfo-0.4.0.0-18341/terminfo-0.4.0.0':
configure: error: curses headers could not be found, so this package cannot be built
See `config.log' for more details
Failed to install terminfo-0.4.0.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
terminfo-0.4.0.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

What do I do to install `Hat`?

Comment: configure: error: curses headers could not be found, so this package cannot be built -- not really a Haskell problem per se.  This means you are missing the C language headers for the curses library.  If you are on Linux those headers are usually in a package like libncurse5-dev.  Not sure about OS X, or MS Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're on a Linux of some sort, there should be a system package like "libncurses5-dev" (that's the name in Ubuntu) that you can install to get the curses headers.

Comment: Now I got another question. I will link it to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have curses installed on your system,

```
cabal install terminfo --extra-include-dirs=/path/to/curses/include --extra-lib-dirs=/path/to/curses/lib
```

of course with the appropriate replacement of `/path/to/curses`.

Your platform's package manager might also be able to install terminfo directly, or you might use a separate package manager, i.e. the [Nix package manager](http://nixos.org/nix/) (which is particularly popular with Haskellers).

Comment: I was actually thinking of using NixOs.

Comment: NixOS is cool, but definitely a bit DIY when a package you need isn't in nixpkgs yet. A lot of fun if you enjoy tinkering, though!